# Perl: how to tar and untar all the contents of a directory including files and subdirectories

Tags: perl

I am writing a Perl script and at the end of the script I want to tar all the contents of a specific directory (say `selected`) as say `selected.tar`.

Now, I need to untar `selected.tar` from another perl script in another location to again `selected` directory.

This is my sheer requirement and I need to preserve all the permission levels and untar should be done in `SECURE_EXTRACT_MODE`.

In summary please tell me  how to tar and untar all the contents of a directory including files and subdirectories.

Any help in this context is highly appreciated.

Please let me know if you need any more details.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?  Also, maybe you should say a little more about what you are trying to accomplish with this.  You may be reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/515553/how-can-i-archive-a-directory-in-perl-like-tar-does-in-unix may be of use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this without shelling out to `tar` you will need to use
[`Archive::Tar::Streamed`](https://metacpan.org/module/Archive%3a%3aTar%3a%3aStreamed)
together with
[`File::Find`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aFind). Also, every file must be small enough to be read into the perl process memory in its entirety.

Something like this should do what you want.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use File::Find 'find';
use Archive::Tar::Streamed;

open my $fh, '>:raw', 'selected.tar';
my $tar = Archive::Tar::Streamed->new($fh);

find(sub { $tar->add($File::Find::name) }, '/path/to/selected');

close $fh;
```