# In Perl Script Not able to add a directory to Archive

Tags: windows, perl

I have to add a Windows directory to Archive using Perl Script. After executing the below script only the Directory name is getting archived and the Directory Content under "C:\Software\Postgres" is not included as part of Archive. Can you please help me where I am making mistake in the below script.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Archive::Tar;

tar_BKUP();

sub tar_BKUP{
  my $src_D = 'C:\Software\Postgres';
  my $dst_Tar = 'C:\temp\Postgres.tar';
  my $tar = Archive::Tar->new();
  $tar->add_files($src_D);
  $tar->write($dst_Tar);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515553/how-can-i-archive-a-directory-in-perl-like-tar-does-in-unix I think this answers your question

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have already tried the logic mentioned in the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515553/how-can-i-archive-a-directory-in-perl-like-tar-does-in-unix but that didn't work. Please note I am trying on Windows

Comment: Fun fact, in Perl you do not need to use backslash for Windows paths, you can use regular slash `/` and avoid backslash issues in string interpolation.

Comment: I've added a bit of whitespace to your code. Whitespace is very useful for making your code easy to read. Please consider adding it yourself in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using [File::Find::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Archive::Tar;
use File::Find::Rule;

tar_BKUP();
sub tar_BKUP{
    my $src_D = 'C:/Software/Postgres';
    my $dst_Tar ='C:/temp/Postgres.tar';
    my $tar = Archive::Tar->new();
    my @files = File::Find::Rule->file->in($src_D);
    $tar->add_files(@files);
    $tar->write($dst_Tar);
}
```

See also [How can I archive a directory in Perl like tar does in UNIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/515553/2173773)

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for the [`add_files()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive::Tar#$tar-%3Eadd_files(-@filenamelist-)) method says this:

> **$tar->add_files( @filenamelist )**
>
> Takes a list of filenames and adds them to the in-memory archive.

So you pass it a list of filenames and those files get added to the archive. It looks like you think you can pass it a directory and get all of the files in that directory added in one go. But it's not documented to work like that.

If you know there are no subdirectories below your source directory, then you could do something like this:

```
$tar->add_files( glob( "$src_D/*" ) );
```

But if you need to include the contents of subdirectories, then [Håkon's answer using File::Find::Rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63711757/7231) is a good approach.

If a Perl module isn't working how you expect it to, then checking the documentation is always a good first step :-)